# Chinese abbreviation for the BBC?

Tags: translation, abbreviations

I've been trying to see if there is a simple Chinese abbreviated translation for the BBC. Wasn't there some law disallowing the use of English abbreviations on CCTV before?

The long form translation is: [英国广播公司](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E8%8B%B1%E5%9B%BD%E5%B9%BF%E6%92%AD%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8).

英广 seems like an appropriate abbreviation but I'm not seeing much obvious usage for it.

Ideas?

Comment: Personally, I never heard any abbreviation for BBC

Comment: The way I read the news there, always negative as far as China is concerned, I would say, BBC is: British Biased against China 英国人歧视中国人

Answer (score 0):

**英广** does show some usage.

[Twitter |《庸言》@Fabianduduosaka](https://twitter.com/Fabianduduosaka/status/1209982014150991873?s=20)

> 【萬象】
> 一、英广驻京记者在报道了有基督徒不愿进入官方认可的“三自教会”后，也承认如今“家庭教会”所得到的自由是从前没有的。
> 部分自由，应该是政府与其不认可的“家庭教会”之间相互适应和妥协得来的。“三自教会”一直以来被解释为官方的教会，隶属于中国的宗教事务管理部门，但实质是什么呢？（转下）
>
> [image]

[Enanyang Malaysia](https://www.enanyang.my/%E5%9B%BD%E9%99%85/%E5%81%9C%E6%94%BE%E8%8B%B1%E5%B9%BF%E6%80%BB%E9%83%A8%E5%A4%96-3%E6%AC%A1%E5%BC%95%E7%88%86%E5%8F%AF%E7%96%91%E8%BD%A6)

> **停放英广总部外3次引爆可疑车**
> （伦敦4日综合电）在伦敦的英国广播公司（BBC）外星期一出现一辆可疑车辆，警方拆弹小组用一台机器人，对可疑的客货车执行3次受控制的爆炸。

[Sina](https://cj.sina.com.cn/articles/view/5393673654/p1417cedb602700b8h4)

> 英广记者来鸿：白宫战情室录音外泄 为何牵动华府神经

[Zaobao](https://www.zaobao.com.sg/realtime/world/story20160523-620475)

> 英广记者被禁采访奥巴马越南之行